# Azure AD Assign Roles to Group

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory

I have azure personal account and I have a Global Administrator and Privileged Role Administrator in Azure
when I go to Groups ==> new group I don't see the new checkbox

Azure AD roles can be assigned to the group checkbox. please let me know what I am missing

[image]

Comment: Hi @Sam are you refering to the Group based role assignment `Azure AD roles can be assigned to the group (Preview)- Yes/No` one..?

Comment: Yes I am refering to the Group based role assignment Azure AD roles can be assigned to the group (Preview)

Comment: To use that feature you need to have `Azure AD Premium P1 license in your Azure AD organization`. Please refer to the [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/roles/groups-concept#required-license-plan). Can you please make sure you are having the required licence

Comment: Thank you for your fast response. we have this Azure AD for Office 365 license so this feature is not available to me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To get the `Azure AD roles can be assigned to the group (Preview)` feature visibility in the Azure portal you need to have `Azure AD Premium P1 license in your Azure AD organization`

[image]

If you won't have the right license you will not be able to use this feature

[image]

For more information please refer this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/roles/groups-concept#required-license-plan)